# PowerPC e200z4 Program Counter Decrementing while debugging

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, powerpc

I am trying to debug code on MPC5646C target using a BDI-3000 probe.
The Ram address starts at 0x40000000. The code is loaded on the target from 0x40000000 and onwards.

But when I try to debug the code using single stepping I found the value of PC (Program counter) decrementing by 4 instead of incrementing and thus entering inaccessible memory region. My code doesn't involve any such jump instruction to invalid addresses.

The debugger log is as follows:

```
    PROG5554s2>TI
    Target CPU        : unknown, not supported
    Target state      : debug mode
    Debug entry cause : unknown
    Current PC        : 0x00003534
    Current CR        : 0x20000008
    Current MSR       : 0x00000000
    Current LR        : 0x40000398
PROG5554s2>TI
    Target CPU        : unknown, not supported
    Target state      : debug mode
    Debug entry cause : unknown
    Current PC        : 0x00003530
    Current CR        : 0x20000008
    Current MSR       : 0x00000000
    Current LR        : 0x40000398
PROG5554s2>TI
    Target CPU        : unknown, not supported
    Target state      : debug mode
    Debug entry cause : unknown
    Current PC        : 0x0000352c
    Current CR        : 0x20000008
    Current MSR       : 0x00000000
    Current LR        : 0x40000398
PROG5554s2>TI
    Target CPU        : unknown, not supported
    Target state      : debug mode
    Debug entry cause : unknown
    Current PC        : 0x00003528
    Current CR        : 0x20000008
    Current MSR       : 0x00000000
    Current LR        : 0x40000398
PROG5554s2>TI
    Target CPU        : unknown, not supported
    Target state      : debug mode
    Debug entry cause : unknown
    Current PC        : 0x00003524
    Current CR        : 0x20000008
    Current MSR       : 0x00000000
    Current LR        : 0x40000398
PROG5554s2>TI
    Target CPU        : unknown, not supported
    Target state      : debug mode
    Debug entry cause : unknown
    Current PC        : 0x00003520
```

Can someone please guide me on this matter?

Thanks

Comment: post the code snippet you're stepping through, and the state of other registers too.

Answer (score 0):

`PROG5554s2>TI
    Target CPU        : unknown, not supported`

this error alone should tell you that you need to update the FW of your BDI. If the BDI FW does not support the CPU it can not properly control it. Get the FW from your BDI vendor.

Comment: Currently BDI is not supporting any e200zX cpu and that was the reason I was compelled to use the firmware for MPC55xx family.

Comment: BTW I have resolved this issue by modifying my BDI config file parameters.

Comment: Congratulations. It seems the proccessor (e200zX) is a new one and should be supported. You need to buy the support (yeah, doesn't come free), that's how I get support for new processors (ie P1022, T104x).